# How to make a toast timeout when another toast needs to be displayed?

Tags: android, toast, android-toast

I have 2 buttons and their onClick are connected to these methods a code similar to this:

```
    /** Called when the user clicks button2 */
    public void button1Start(View view) {
        // Display a toast at bottom of screen
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

/** Called when the user clicks button2 */
    public void button2Start(View view) {
        // Display different toast at bottom of screen
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Now, as expected when I click on these buttons, the toasts appear on bottom of screen one at a time after the previous one times-out.

What I need is this behavior: when I click button2 the "Toast2" view should immediately replace "Toast1" irrespective of the duration of "Toast1". Is there any way to achieve this? Can I make "toast1" to timeout or maybe make the toast1 view invisible?

Comment: No you can't do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the same Toast object to show your text.

Maybe you should create a singleton to use in your entire application, but the shortest way is:

```
private Toast mToast;

private void showMessage(String message) {
    if (mToast == null) {
        mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    } else {
        mToast.setText(message);
    }
    mToast.show();
}
```

No need to cancel. The previous text is immediately replaced, if any.

Comment: That does seem like a good option. However, is there a way to achieve this without using any variables outside the two buttonStart methods(button1start or button2start)?

Comment: Toast is a singleton, you don't need to keep reference to it. You wrote the same that @Yogesh in question(just modified it) . The second message will appear after time will come of first.

Comment: IgorB, Toast is not a singleton. When you call makeText(), the method instantiate a new Toast object and return to you.

Comment: @Yogesh, there is no way, you need to keep the object somewhere. Maybe you should create your own singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make toast invisible, but you can make delay for it(but I think it's not a good practice)

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Toast2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: But will this not just cause the toast to not be displayed for a while if I only press button1? Also it will not really change to toast2 when I click button2 immediately.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make a toast timeout when another toast needs to be displayed?

#### No that´s not possible!.

Have you tried with `cancel()` method?

```
Toast mytoast;
mytoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi Ho Jorgesys! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
mytoast.show();
....
....
....
if(CancelToast){
  mytoast.cancel();
}
```

Comment: How exactly will the CancelToast part work? Which event will trigger that?

Comment: you have to determinate when are you going to cancel the toast, for example you will do that inside an onClick method.